# Shaky Effect in ScrollView Scrolling - Scroll to Specific Point when clicked on btn

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am experiencing this shaking effect whenever I click on top buttons. If someone observe carefully, he can see that the top btns shake on scrolling.[image: Top Btns are shaking whenever there's some scrolling]

```
const [sectionHeights, setSectionHeights] = useState([]);
const [aboveComponentHeight, setAboveComponentHeight] = useState(0);
const debouncedScrollToComponent = debounce((index, txt) => {
  setActiveButton(txt);
}, 100);

const scrollToComponent = (index, txt) => {
  if (scrollViewRef.current && sectionRefs.current[index]) {
    const buttonSectionHeight = sectionHeights
      .slice(0, index)
      .reduce((acc, height) => acc + height, 0);

    const offsetY = buttonSectionHeight + aboveComponentHeight;

    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: offsetY, animated: true });
    debouncedScrollToComponent(index, txt);
  }
};

const onSectionLayout = (event, index) => {
  const { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  setSectionHeights((prevHeights) => {
    const updatedHeights = [...prevHeights];
    updatedHeights[index] = height;
    return updatedHeights;
  });
};

const onAboveComponentLayout = (event) => {
  const { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  console.log('aboveComponentHeight', height);
  setAboveComponentHeight(height);
};

<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 60 }}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
>
  <View ref={aboveComponentRef} onLayout={onAboveComponentLayout}>
    //other code
  </View>
  {/* Section Buttons */}
  <View>
    <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
      {Btns.map((txt, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.7}
          onPress={() => scrollToComponent(index, txt)}
          key={index}
          style={txt == activeButton ? styles.activeBtn : styles.inactiveBtn}
        >
          <Text style={activeButton == txt ? styles.activeText : styles.inactiveText}>
            {txt}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  </View>
  {/* Suppliers */}
  <View
    style={styles.supplierContainer}
    ref={(ref) => (sectionRefs.current[0] = ref)}
    onLayout={(event) => onSectionLayout(event, 0)}
  >
    //other code
  </View>
  {/* Description */}
  <View
    ref={(ref) => (sectionRefs.current[1] = ref)}
    style={{ padding: 16 }}
    onLayout={(event) => onSectionLayout(event, 1)}
  >
    //other code
  </View>

  {/* Product Specs */}
  <View
    ref={(ref) => (sectionRefs.current[2] = ref)}
    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 16 }}
    onLayout={(event) => onSectionLayout(event, 2)}
  >
    //Other code
  </View>
  <Divider bgColor={'#EFEFEF'} my={3} />
  {/* Reviews */}
  <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 16 }}>
    //other code
  </View>
</ScrollView>;
```

I am using the above code to calculate the height of the content that is above the section btns and including section btns. I have also tried using setTimeout function but still no success.

The main issue is whenever I click on any of the btns, the whole btn section shakes a little and someone can clearly see that it is not smooth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try turning on Slow Animations in the simulator and re-record? I can't see shaking. I do see a color change that may be unwanted.

Comment: Here is the link of video:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1314tRI7S9S2VOoo0Vs56YRpAX4K3YK47?usp=sharing